# Testing then and catch from a promise in angular

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

I would like to test my then and catch function from my $scope.customerinfo. The problem is i dont know how exactly.

```
    var app = angular.module('shop', ['ngRoute','ngResource'])
      .factory('Customerservice', function ($resource) {
          return $resource('http://localhost:8080/Shop/:customer',{customer: "@customer"});
    })
      .controller('customerController', function ($scope,Customerservice) {
         $scope.customerinfo = CustomerService.get({customer: "Mark"});
         $scope.customerinfo.$promise.then(function(info) {
            return info;
         }).catch(function(errorResponse) {
            throw errorResponse;
         });
});
```

Im not done yet but this is my jasmine code

```
describe('Testing the customerinfo', function () {
  var $scope;
  var $q;
  var deferred;

  beforeEach(module('shop'));

  beforeEach(inject(function($controller, _$rootScope_, _$q_) {
    $q = _$q_;
    $scope = _$rootScope_.$new();
    deferred = _$q_.defer();
    $controller('userController', {
      $scope: $scope
    });
    }));
    it('should reject promise', function () {
   // I want to check if the catch option is working
  });
});
```

So how exactly can i do this, or do i need to refactor the code?

Comment: I don't really understand the point of the code in the controller: it maps a successful response to the exact same successful response, and maps an error response to the exact same error response. And it does nothing with the returned promise anyway.

Comment: the only reason i do this, is cause i want to wait till the async get request is done.(i'm just a beginner but it works this way) I know that it does nothing with the returned promise thats because im not finished yet with the programming. I just want to test the then and catch function right now.

Comment: There is no way, since they don't have any side effect, and the return value is not stored anywhere. It's just a noop.

Comment: Check out http://chaijs.com/plugins/chai-as-promised/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The jasmine 'it' method takes a done parameter that you can call for async testing

```
it('Should reject', function(done) {
  someAsyncFunction().catch(function(result) {
    expect(result.status).toBe(401);
    done();
  });
});
```